# Can I return an object of some class from Flask?

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I am using `flask.ext.restful` api and hitting the API for an object.

I have a class X.
I create an object of that class.
Now I want to return this object to the jQuery request.

```
object_of_x=X()
print object_of_x  # output -> <X instance at 0x3602cb0>
return object_of_x
```

It gives me an error.
It works fine when I do a `render_template('x.html',x=object_of_x)`

Is there no way to return an instance of some class using Flask or `flask.ext.restful`?

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is to serialize the object into a JSON string, or XML, and return that. On the client side just create a JS object from the received string.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to return... you could define the `__dict__` method on your class and then use `return jsonify(x.__dict__)` in your route.

```
>>> class X(object):
...   def __init__(self, thing1, thing2):
...     self.thing1 = thing1
...     self.thing2 = thing2
>>> x = X("hey", "listen")
>>> from json import dumps as jsonstring
>>> jsonstring(x.__dict__)
'{"thing2": "listen", "thing1": "hey"}'
```

Comment: Ya. I understand that. But the problem is the class I have has a list of objects of some other class. Eg: class X(): list=[list oF Class Y]  so __dict__ doesnt work on that.